# "Such level of shade for her age" - meaning of "level of shade" in a YouTube comment on an actress taking part in a talk show

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, slang

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tIKgq06Zzw) (a very young urbane actress being interviewed on a late-night TV show) and came across the comment that I couldn't understand:

> Such **level of shade** for her age... I see great things in her future.

Is it a poorly constructed sentence or does "shade" convey any other subtle meaning I'm not aware of?

Judging from the context, I can assume "shade" could mean "sophistication", or "mystery", or "variety", but it's rather random.

I scanned a dictionary, didn't find anything appropriate.

I would love it if you helped me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Shade*** has relatively recently become a slang term for expressing disdain, contempt, dislike, etc. Indicating that someone is stupid, is not worth your time, is generally worthless or not worthy of attention. It is usually expressed as the object of the verb *to throw* (as in "she's really throwing some **shade** now"), but can be expressed with other verbs or with no verb at all.

Comment: Thank you for a good answer. Now I am confused about the diff between "to throw shade" and "to throw shadow", are they different?

Comment: Yes. To throw *shadow* is the same as to throw *a shadow*, meaning to block a source of light form reaching someone. It's entirely literal, standard English for a very long time. To throw *shade* is a recent development in vernacular English that has caught on widely in some communities.